# Stopping jobs by PID?

Tags: bash, process, kill

Could someone tell me why I am unable to kill the jobs below when specifying their PID? I can stop the jobs when using their % id.

Mac:~ gd$ ps

PID TTY           TIME CMD

4523 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash

4560 ttys000    0:00.00 gpg

4609 ttys000    0:00.00 gpg

Mac:~ gd$ kill 4560

Mac:~ gd$ kill 4609

Mac:~ gd$ exit

logout

There are stopped jobs.

Mac:~ g$ jobs

[1]-  Stopped                 gpg

[2]+  Stopped                 gpg

Mac:~ gd$ kill %1

gpg: signal Terminated caught ... exiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `kill %n` will run the shell builtin, which will make sure stopped jobs are sent `SIGCONT` so that they can realize they've been killed.

To achieve that with PIDs of stopped jobs, you need to:

```
kill $pid
```

(Or `kill -TERM $pid` if you want to make it explicit)

and then

```
kill -CONT $pid
```

You don't need the `-CONT` if you go for the ultimate murder weapon:

```
kill -KILL $pid
```